# Automated jobs fail in SSIS send mail task?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, sendmail

Few automated jobs that run through SQL Server Agent in SQL Server 2008 fail in the SSIS send mail task.  When I open ssis and build the job to re run the job runs fine.  The code is entered in an "Execute SQL Task" and it is something along these lines:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@recipients='andi@myemail.com',
@query='select from sometable',
@subject= 'Your Subject',
@message= 'THE EMAIL HAS BEEN SENT'
```

Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: What is the precise failure message? Is the SQL Server Agent Account authorized to send email?

Comment: Yes, it says "parameters not set correctly or problems with the query or connection not established correctly".